# How Effective is jsfiddle with JQuery Mobile 1.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am new to this coding world. I actually have spent the last 2 days reading more about code than I care to admit to myself.  However,  I am curious to know how effect is the jsfiddle site with the JQuery Mobile.

I have started a project and am debugging as much as possible. However the end goal is to make a simple quote form application for use with Phonegap for a company I work for.

this is a link http://jsfiddle.net/6Vxw5/57/ to my code that I am working with.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#model").change(function(){
        $("div[id^='div']").hide();                
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == "1"){
           $("#div1").show();
        }
        if(val == "2"){
           $("#div3").show();
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="model">
<option id="select" value="0">Please Select</option>
<option id="DXV35_III" value="1">Mendota DXV 35 DeepTimber Fire III Direct Vent Gas Fireplace</option>
<option id="DXV45_III" value="2">Mendota DXV 45 DeepTimber Fire III Direct Vent Gas Fireplace</option>
<option id="DXV35" value="3">Mendota DXV 35 Time Fire Direct Vent Gas Fire Place</option>
    <option id="DXV42" value="4">Mendota DXV 42 Direct Vent Gas Fireplace</option>
</select>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;"><ul class="checkbox-grid">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="value1" /><label for="text1">Text 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text2" value="value2" /><label for="text2">Text 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text3" value="value3" /><label for="text3">Text 3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text4" value="value4" /><label for="text4">Text 4</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="value5" /><label for="text5">Text 5</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text6" value="value6" /><label for="text6">Text 6</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text7" value="value7" /><label for="text7">Text 7</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="text8" value="value8" /><label for="text8">Text 8</label></li>
   </ul></div>
```

It looks nice and promising when I launch it in the JQuery 1.7.2 Framework & Extentsions, however with the JQuery Mobile 1.1.1 when I use my drop down menu it generates redundant text.   What am I doing wrong with my code?

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LcPQ.png

Comment: EDIT: This is fixed now I changed some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some settings on JSfiddle, as I was encoding with deprecated items